# Force do not occur R Session Aborted in RStudio

Tags: r, loops, rstudio, glmmtmb

I'd like to create a loop for several GLMM models, but I know that some factor is not possible to fit. I create some parameters to avoid errors like `skip_to_next <- FALSE`, `tryCatch`, and a minimum of points restriction (`if(length(unique(NEW_DS_F_pred_sub$DATE))>=4)`).
Despite all of these steps I always have `R Session Aborted` and I don't find any way to just ignore the not-so-good-to-fit factors.

In my example:

```
library("glmmTMB")
library("dplyr")
library("ggeffects")
library("ggplot2")

NEW_DS_F_pred <- NULL
STAND <- c(rep("A",5),rep("B",3),rep("C",6),rep("D",4))
stands <- unique(STAND)
DATE <- c("2022-01-01","2022-02-12","2022-03-01","2022-04-05","2022-06-01",
"2022-01-01","2022-02-12","2022-03-01",
"2022-01-01","2022-02-12","2022-03-01","2022-04-05","2022-06-01","2022-06-20",
"2022-01-01","2022-02-12","2022-03-01","2022-04-05")
B2_MAX <- runif(n=length(DATE))
B3_MAX <- runif(n=length(DATE))
B4_MAX <- runif(n=length(DATE))
NEW_DS_F_pred <- cbind(STAND,DATE,B2_MAX,B3_MAX,B4_MAX) %>% as.data.frame()

for (i in 1:length(stands)){
        skip_to_next <- FALSE
        tryCatch(print(stands[i]), error = function(e) { skip_to_next <<- TRUE})

NEW_DS_F_pred_sub <- NEW_DS_F_pred%>%filter(STAND==stands[i])

if(length(unique(NEW_DS_F_pred_sub$DATE))>=4){

NEW_DS_F_pred_sub$DATE_TIME <- as.numeric(difftime(NEW_DS_F_pred_sub$DATE, as.Date("2022-06-30"), units = "days"))
NEW_DS_F_pred_sub$DATE_TIME <- as.numeric(NEW_DS_F_pred_sub$DATE_TIME)
NEW_DS_F_pred_sub$B2_MAX <- as.numeric(NEW_DS_F_pred_sub$B2_MAX)
NEW_DS_F_pred_sub$B3_MAX <- as.numeric(NEW_DS_F_pred_sub$B3_MAX)
NEW_DS_F_pred_sub$B4_MAX <- as.numeric(NEW_DS_F_pred_sub$B4_MAX)
NEW_DS_F_pred_sub<-as.data.frame(NEW_DS_F_pred_sub)

# Fit the model B2_MAX
glmm_fit_B2_MAX <- glmmTMB(B2_MAX ~ poly(DATE_TIME,3) + (1|DATE_TIME), data=NEW_DS_F_pred_sub, family=tweedie(link = "log"))
ggeffects::ggpredict(glmm_fit_B2_MAX, terms = "DATE_TIME [all]") %>% plot(add.data = TRUE) + 
  xlab('Time in days') +
  ylab('VI 1')

# Predict the values
glmm_fit_B2_MAX_new <- NULL
glmm_fit_B2_MAX_new$DATE_TIME <- seq(-180,1)
glmm_fit_B2_MAX_new$B2_MAX <- predict(
  glmm_fit_B2_MAX,
  newdata = glmm_fit_B2_MAX_new,
  type = c("response"))
glmm_fit_B2_MAX_new$STAND <- rep(stands[i], length(glmm_fit_B2_MAX_new$DATE_TIME)) 
glmm_fit_B2_MAX_new <- as.data.frame(glmm_fit_B2_MAX_new)
glmm_fit_B2_MAX_new <- glmm_fit_B2_MAX_new%>%dplyr::select(STAND,DATE_TIME,B2_MAX)

# Fit the model B3_MAX
glmm_fit_B3_MAX <- glmmTMB(B3_MAX ~ poly(DATE_TIME,3) + (1|DATE_TIME), data=NEW_DS_F_pred_sub, family=tweedie(link = "log"))

# Predict the values
glmm_fit_B3_MAX_new <- NULL
glmm_fit_B3_MAX_new$DATE_TIME <- seq(-180,1)
glmm_fit_B3_MAX_new$B3_MAX <- predict(
  glmm_fit_B3_MAX,
  newdata = glmm_fit_B3_MAX_new,
  type = c("response"))
glmm_fit_B3_MAX_new$STAND <- rep(stands[i], length(glmm_fit_B3_MAX_new$DATE_TIME)) 
glmm_fit_B3_MAX_new <- as.data.frame(glmm_fit_B3_MAX_new)

# Fit the model B4_MAX
glmm_fit_B4_MAX <- glmmTMB(B4_MAX ~ poly(DATE_TIME,3) + (1|DATE_TIME), data=NEW_DS_F_pred_sub, family=tweedie(link = "log"))

# Predict the values
glmm_fit_B4_MAX_new <- NULL
glmm_fit_B4_MAX_new$DATE_TIME <- seq(-180,1)
glmm_fit_B4_MAX_new$B4_MAX <- predict(
  glmm_fit_B4_MAX,
  newdata = glmm_fit_B4_MAX_new,
  type = c("response"))
glmm_fit_B4_MAX_new$STAND <- rep(stands[i], length(glmm_fit_B4_MAX_new$DATE_TIME)) 
glmm_fit_B4_MAX_new <- as.data.frame(glmm_fit_B4_MAX_new)

if(skip_to_next) { next }     
}
}
#
#
```

[image: boomRstudio]

Is there any way to force the loop to continuos without R Session Aborted?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't replicate the problem.  I get lots of warnings, but R doesn't crash.  I can't see why it would make a difference, but can you try running this outside of RStudio, on the command line?

Comment: Sorry Prof. @BenBolker now I corrected the code. If not crash, please repeat sometimes. Thans.

Comment: Again, when I run this code (i.e., the new version after your edits) it doesn't stop. (I'm not sure what " If not crash, please repeat sometimes." means ...)

Comment: "please repeat sometimes" means that a cause a random `runif` value sometimes the loop crash and sometimes not. I found the same results in two different machines, both w11 and R4.1.3.

Comment: Can you reproduce the crash when running the script outside of R Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can install the most recent development version of TMB via

```r
remotes::install_github("kaskr/adcomp/TMB")
```

(you will need development tools installed), that will apply a bug fix and stop R from crashing.

---

I made a function with your code inside, of the following form:

```r
do <- function(seed=NULL) {
    if (!is.null(seed)) {   
          cat("seed ", seed, "\n")
          set.seed(seed)
    }
    ## ... all of your code
}
```

And then ran

```r
for (i in 1:200) { 
   do(i+100)
}
```

at `i==11` it terminated my R session with

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'; what():  cannot create std::vector larger than max_size()
> Process R aborted (core dumped) at Fri Nov  3 20:17:28 2023

Now I can run `do(111)` and get it to crash immediately.

Now I can/will step through the code and/or run `debug()` on the function to see what aspects of the data for this random number seed are making the problem explode.

---

After stepping through (with `debug()`), I found where the crash happened (on the fourth step (stand D), at the first model B2). I used

```r
saveRDS(NEW_DS_F_pred_sub, file = "SO77422084_bad.rds")
```

to save the "bad" data frame (I've tried `dput()`, but it doesn't seem to work ...)

Now this minimal code will crash R:

```r
library(glmmTMB)
NEW_DS_F_pred_sub <- readRDS("SO77422084_bad.rds")
## trim data set to make it even more minimal
bad <- NEW_DS_F_pred_sub[c("DATE_TIME", "B2_MAX")]
glmm_fit_B2_MAX <- glmmTMB(B2_MAX ~ poly(DATE_TIME,3) + 
                                   (1|DATE_TIME), data=bad,
                               family=tweedie(link = "log"))
```

will crash R.

A minimal example with a little bit more code, but that runs from scratch (i.e. not requiring us to run a bunch of code and save the results to an external file):

```r
set.seed(111)
dd <- data.frame( STAND = rep(LETTERS[1:4], c(5,3,6,4)),
   DATE = c("2022-01-01","2022-02-12","2022-03-01","2022-04-05",
    "2022-06-01","2022-01-01","2022-02-12","2022-03-01",
    "2022-01-01","2022-02-12","2022-03-01","2022-04-05",
    "2022-06-01","2022-06-20","2022-01-01","2022-02-12",
                              "2022-03-01","2022-04-05"))
    dd$B2_MAX <- runif(n=nrow(dd))
    dd_sub <- subset(dd, STAND == "D")
    dd_sub$DATE_TIME <-as.numeric(difftime(dd_sub$DATE, as.Date("2022-06-30"), units = "days"))
glmmTMB(B2_MAX ~ poly(DATE_TIME,3) + 
                (1|DATE_TIME), data=dd_sub,
            family=tweedie(link = "log"))
```

Weirdly, running `dput()` on `bad` and redefining `bad` to that value:

```r
bad <- structure(list(DATE_TIME = c(-179.791666666667, -137.791666666667, 
                 -120.791666666667, -85.8333333333333),
         B2_MAX = c(0.156202515820041, 0.446427763439715, 
    0.171443687053397, 0.9665342932567)),
                     row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

will *not* crash R — there must some very subtle difference between the data set as stored in binary format and what happens when the ASCII representation is created ...

I then did `debug(glmmTMB)` and stepped my way through `glmmTMB`. The crash happens while R is trying to run the optimization, at [this point in the code](https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/blob/5939686f39b169b7d5a81512b6a66025f103d598/glmmTMB/R/glmmTMB.R#L1602-L1605).

Debugging further, into `nlminb`, I find that the crash occurs here:

```r
.Call(C_port_nlminb, obj, grad, hess, rho, low, upp, d = rep_len(as.double(scale), 
    length(par)), iv, v)
```

For what it's worth this also crashes if I switch optimizers by using

```r
control=glmmTMBControl(optimizer=optim, optArgs=list(method="BFGS"))
```

so it must not be the optimizer's fault, but rather that some set of parameters encountered during optimization that triggers the crash.

The next thing I'll do (not tonight!) is to figure out an appropriate way of tracing the parameters that are being tried by the optimizer so we can figure out the exact parameters that are causing the crash (and, hopefully, fix what looks like a bug in `glmmTMB`)

See [here](https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/962) for much more fussing over this bug.

Comment: Amazing explanation Prof. @BenBolker!!! Now I'd a new approach based in model parameters. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Hi Prof. @BenBolker a palliative solution that I found for avoiding `bad` values that reduce a lot the crash was `control = glmmTMBControl(optimizer=nlminb, optCtrl = list(iter.max=9, eval.max=9))`, extreme ugly but work until now.

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, though, that means that you will often be stopping the optimizer long before it gets to the solution.  Can you apply the bug fix I suggested, and does that resolve the problem?

Comment: Hi, Prof. @BenBolker thanks for your solution and code implementation in `glmmTMB`. Now I'm using our suggested solution.